# Circular data in machine learning algorithms

Tags: machine-learning, circular-dependency, circular-reference, hsl

I have a circular data (color component Hue of HSL) and I need to use it as predictor in one of the machine learning algorithms.
How can I convert it to the regular continuous variable?

In order to clarify the problem, suppose we have an object in red. The predictor **hue**, for instance, takes its value in two separated range [0, 60] and [300, 359]. Most of the machine learning algorithms find the mean (average) of the predictors. Therefore, the mean will lie into the range [150, 210] which refer to the cyan color! That happens because hue is circular data..

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This seems to answer you question
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/218407/encoding-angle-data-for-neural-network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Decompose the single digit circular data into 2 dimensional x,y or cos0 / sin0 data.

Imagine time as data.

11:59.35... PM (14399) is a minute away from 12:00AM (00000)

but the algorithm interprets 14399.35.. as far away from 00000 when in fact they should be close

The option I suggest is to map the data into points in a unit circle.
From here there are two ways to transform the data.

1. Get the x,y coordinates of the data from the unit circle
   ex. 14399.35 = [-0.01, 0.99]
   00000.00 = [ 00.0, 1.00]
2. Get the sin/cos of the points in the unit circle with respect to the center
   ex. 14399.35 = [0.1,-0.9]
   00000.00 = [0.89,-0.4]

thus we get a result where the circular data now has values that are comparable with each other

note: these are not the exact values, they're just here for demonstration